# Using text(), is there a way to convert empty text to 'None' with scrapy

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm running into a problem. The website xml I'm scraping has some values that are empty, but I need to preserve the order of the values.

sample:

```
<thedata>
    <some-item>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value>44</value>
        <value>32</value>
        <value>31</value>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value>32</value>
        <value>31</value>
        <value>34</value>
        <value>34</value>
        <value>33</value>
    </some-item>
</thedata>
```

Doing `text()` will ignore empty values:

```
class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/somexml.xml']
    itertag = 'thedata'

    # Using XMLFeedSpider
    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        item_vals = node.select('some-item/value/text()').extract()
        print item_vals
```

This will print a list which contains only values that have an integer.

Since I need to preserve order, is there a way to tell scrapy to replace any empty values with `''` or `None`?

**EDIT**:
@unutbu: I'm still getting the same problem:

```
    item_vals = node.select('some-item/value/text()').extract()
    print item_vals
    item_vals2 = node.select('some-item/value/text()').extract() or None
    print item_vals2
```

Output:

```
    [u'44',u'32',u'31',u'32',u'31',u'34',u'34',u'33']
    [u'44',u'32',u'31',u'32',u'31',u'34',u'34',u'33']
```

What I want is:

```
    [None,None,None,None,None,u'44',u'32',u'31',None,None,u'32',u'31',u'34',u'34',u'33']
```

Or something that represents an empty value when it is encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select **all** the value nodes, and then extract the text (if any) from each piece:

```
[txt for item in hxs.select('some-item/value') for txt in item.select('text()').extract() or [u'']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I still get the problem. I updated my post about it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question... (Answer has been changed accordingly.)

Comment: I don't get any data if I use `elt.text`. If I just print out `elt`, I get this unicode:
`<value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true"/>`  (Sorry about the namespace, I couldn't get that to work with XMLFeedSpider for whatever reason)

Comment: Doing `[elt.extract() for ...]` does the same as `node.select().extract()`. That is, it just prints out the unicode of `<value ...>`

Comment: Bak, I apologize -- I misunderstood your question originally, and now I've waded into something I don't really know. I'll delete this answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Bak, by playing around with `scrapy shell http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample2.html` I think I found a way which works, but it isn't pretty.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does work!! I'll accept this answer. If anyone has a cleaner answer, I'd like to know as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [Becker](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/) method:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
>>> xml = """<thedata>
...     <some-item>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value>44</value>
...         <value>32</value>
...         <value>31</value>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value xsi:nil="true"/>
...         <value>32</value>
...         <value>31</value>
...         <value>34</value>
...         <value>34</value>
...         <value>33</value>
...     </some-item>
... </thedata>
... """
>>> xxs = XmlXPathSelector(text=xml)
>>> thedata = xxs.select('some-item/value').select(
... 'concat('
... ' substring(text(), 1, number(text()) * string-length(text())),'
... ' substring("nil", 1, number(not(text())) * string-length("nil")))'
... ).extract()
>>> thedata
[u'nil', u'nil', u'nil', u'nil', u'nil', u'44', u'32', u'31', u'nil', u'nil', u'32', u'31', u'34', u'34', u'33']
```

and if you want to get the `None` values:

```
>>> map(lambda v: None if v == 'nil' else v, thedata)
[None, None, None, None, None, u'44', u'32', u'31', None, None, u'32', u'31', u'34', u'34', u'33']
```